# Java Virtual Machine Specification

Tags: java, performance, jvm

> The Java Virtual Machine knows nothing of the Java programming
> language, only of a particular binary format, the class file format. A
> class file contains Java Virtual Machine instructions (or bytecodes)
> and a symbol table, as well as other ancillary information.
>
> For the
> sake of security, the Java Virtual Machine imposes strong syntactic
> and structural constraints on the code in a class file. However, any
> language with functionality that can be expressed in terms of a valid
> class file can be hosted by the Java Virtual Machine. Attracted by a
> generally available, machine-independent platform, implementors of
> other languages can turn to the Java Virtual Machine as a delivery
> vehicle for their languages.

I could not understand the last paragraph what he's saying .Can you help me please .Specially the last 4 rows of the last paragraph.

Comment: Um, it's saying that languages other than Java can target the JVM. It's not clear what part of that is causing problems. Rather than "the last 4 rows" (which might mean different things on different machines anyway), please be as specific as you can.

Comment: What do you think it is saying? It's very hard to find out what your problem in understanding this is if you don't give is clues to what your problem could be.

Comment: I just want to confirm what i understand from the last 4 lines and which case is valid. Is it case A or case B?
A)
Different languages having their logics can use java ,just like in web services, for the completion of its functionality.

B) the functionality of other languages can be converted in java as language and that is supported by jvm.Due to this programmers of other languages shift from their technology to java .

Comment: Neither. It says that other languages might get compiled into *class files* containing Java byte code to run on a JVM. They are not converted to the Java programming language.

Comment: Thank You guys .@ john@holger@erwin

Answer (score 1):

It means that even though the JVM was created for `Java` to use, it can also be (and is) targeted by other languages, such as `Scala`, `Groovy` etc. which have different syntax from Java code.